# Can I overlap div elements with clipped paths in CSS without masking the child div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create two trapezoids using CSS and have them overlay on top of one another.  The problem is that when I use the clip-path attribute, it automatically masks the other div below it.   Is there any way for me to create a background image similar to the attached image without using absolute positioning in my div elements?

An example of what I've done so far:

```css
.bg1 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 100px 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 18%, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0 100%);
}
.bg2 {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  padding: 100px 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 13%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg1">
  <div class="bg2">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example:

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pseudo elements:

```css
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 15%, 100% 85%, 0 100%);
}

.box::after {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  transform: scaleX(-1); /* the shape is the same so I simple invert it but you can apply another clip-path here */ 
}

.box {
  padding:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

You can also do it without pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  --v:15%;
  
  padding:50px;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% var(--v), 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% calc(100% - var(--v)), 0 100%);
  background:
      linear-gradient(to top    left,transparent 48%,red 50%) top    -1px left 0,
      linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 48%,red 50%) bottom -1px left 0,
      #3f3f3f;
  background-size:100% calc(2*var(--v));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--v:10%">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--v:5%">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```